# How can I debug handlebars in node in VS Code?

Tags: node.js, debugging, visual-studio-code, handlebars.js, express-handlebars

I am trying to render a .hbs file

```
res.render('./reporting/review_email.hbs', { ..._data, layout: false });
```

however the .hbs file is not properly rendering because there is a property of the _data object which is either missing or incorrect. I know that this is the case because when I replace _data with a JSON object that is manually populated (as opposed to from the database), the template renders fine.

I am wondering how I could debug the issue in VSCode.
Basically I want to know where the compiler encounters the problem.

Comment: Why can't you simply step inside the function call? But you will need very good understanding of handlebars to do this. Why don't you start by `JSON.stringify(data)`  and `JSON.stringify(working)` and then compare these.

Comment: Thanks and yes, that is a way to do it. It would be nice to be able to see from the compiler where the error is as the above is fiddly.